# how do I define a system of delay differential equation using DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to define a system of delay differential equations.  So far I have:

```
eqn1 := {P'[t] == -gamma*P[t] + (((theta)^m)/(theta)^m)*Q[t] - 
     Exp[-gamma*tau]*Q[t - tau] - eps[s]*P[t], 
   Q'[t] == -beta0*Q[t] - delta*Q[t] + 2*Exp[-gamma*tau], P[0] == 50, 
   Q[t /; t <= 0] == 10};

DSolve[eqn1, {P[t], Q[t]}, t]
{pans1[t_], qans1[t_]} = 
 ExpandAll[{P[t], Q[t]} /. Flatten[DSolve[eqn1, {P[t], Q[t]}, t]]]
```

I am trying to start simple by only putting the delay in the term `Q[t-tau]` in the equation `P'[t]`.  Once I figure this out, I will have a similar term in the equation for `Q'[t]`. Before I added the term with the delay, I simply had `Q[0==10]` for the initial condition.  I changed this to `Q[t /; t <= 0] == 10` when I put in the delay term but I think this is incorrect or incomplete.  I would really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 2):

The code as written generates the `DSolve::litarg` error message.  It can be eliminated by using

```
DSolve[eqn1, {P[t], Q[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

(The upper limit of integration can be chosen arbitrarily, because this is an initial value problem.)  Unfortunately, `DSolve` returns unevaluated.  Adding the option, `Assumptions -> tau > 0` does not help.

Nonetheless, progress can be made.  Because the ODE for `Q` is independent of `P`, it can be solved separately.

```
tol[t_] = Piecewise[{{DSolveValue[{Q'[t] == -beta0*Q[t] - delta*Q[t] + 
    2*Exp[-gamma*tau], Q[0] == 10}, Q[t], t] // Simplify, t > 0}}, 10]

(* Piecewise[{{(2*E^(-(beta0*t) - delta*t - gamma*tau)*(-1 + E^((beta0 + delta)*t) + 
       5*(beta0 + delta)*E^(gamma*tau)))/(beta0 + delta), t > 0}}, 10] *)
```

Then insert `tol` in place of `Q` in the ODE for `P`.

```
DSolveValue[{P'[t] == -gamma*P[t] + (((theta)^m)/(theta)^m)*tol[t] - 
    Exp[-gamma*tau]*tol[t - tau] - eps*P[t], P[0] == 50}, P[t], t, 
    Assumptions -> tau > 0] // Simplify
```

After several minutes a solution too long to be reproduced here (with a `LeafCount` of `1848`) results.

This is not the first time that I have seen `DSolve` fail to solve a set of ODEs but succeed in solving subsets of them that, when combined, give the solution to the original problem.